# Query/Filter method resulting in NameError

Tags: python, debugging, sqlalchemy, traceback

I have a table with two (M-1) relationships with respective ForeignKeys. I want to verify that ids match. I attempted to compare ids and am receiving: `NameError: global name 'owner_id' is not defined`

I am uncertain why this is the issue. I wasn't sure if I should use a `join` method per SQLAlchemy docs, but it is within the table. Calling `self.` also doesn't work.

The table is:

```
class Assessment_Results(Base):
            __tablename__ = 'assessment_results'

            id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
            created_on = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

            owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
            owner = relationship('User', backref='assessment_results')

            assessment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('assessments.assessment_id'))
            assessment = relationship('Assessment', backref='assessment_results')

            def __init__(self, owner, assessment):
                self.owner = owner
                self.assessment = assessment
```

The query:

```
def retrieve_assessment_results(self, owner, assessment): 
    assess_results = self.session.query(Assessment_Results).\
    filter(Assessment_Results.id == owner_id).\
    filter(Assessment_Results.id == assessment_id).all()
    return assess_results
```

Entire Traceback:

```
ERROR: notssdb.test.test.test1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 86, in test1
    api.create_category_rating(2, 'Decision-Making', 'baseball', 'Becoming a Leader')
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/convenience.py", line 29, in create_category_rating
    assessment_results = self.retrieve_assessment_results(owner, assessment)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/object.py", line 273, in retrieve_assessment_results
    filter(Assessment_Results.id == owner_id).\
NameError: global name 'owner_id' is not defined
```

---

New Traceback Error after this new implementation:

```
def retrieve_assessment_results(self, owner, assessment): 
    assess_results = self.session.query(Assessment_Results).\
    filter(Assessment_Results.owner_id == owner.id).\
    filter(Assessment_Results.assessment_id == assessment.id).all()
    return assess_results
```

Inheritance class of the method above:

```
def create_assessment_results(self, username, name):
    owner = self.retrieve_user(username)
    assessment = self.retrieve_assessment(name)
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_assessment_results(owner, assessment)
```

Here is cat_rating :

```
def create_category_rating(self, category_rating_int, category_name, owner, assessment):
    category = self.retrieve_category(category_name)
    assessment_results = self.retrieve_assessment_results(owner, assessment)
    return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_category_rating(category_rating_int, category, assessment_results)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 86, in test1
    api.create_category_rating(2, 'Decision-Making', 'baseball', 'Becoming a Leader')
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/convenience.py", line 29, in create_category_rating
    assessment_results = self.retrieve_assessment_results(owner, assessment)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/api/object.py", line 272, in retrieve_assessment_results
    filter(Assessment_Results.owner_id == owner.id).\
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line right here..

```
filter(Assessment_Results.id == owner_id).\
```

owner_id was not defined in this method and is not being accessed as an attribute of an Assessment_Results object, so the interpreter doesn't know what object you are trying to refer to by this name.

I think you probably want to do

```
filter(Assessment_Results.owner_id == owner.id).\
```

but that assumes that owner is an instance of the owner model.

You'll end up having the same problem with assessment_id (because it is also not defined within the method) once you figure out what variable you meant to use for owner_id.

Comment: I think what you want is 

filter(Assessment_Results.owner_id == owner.id).\

etc. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No I mean owner_id doesn't exist anywhere, so you must have meant something else

Comment: this makes sense:  `filter(Assessment_Results.owner_id == owner.id)` but I notice the id is not storing in the other entities when I call this `retrieve_` method.

Comment: The method you suggest gives me the same `TracebackError` stating that `owner_id` is not defined.

Comment: @amarie when you say "but the issue is that adding Assessment_Results.owner_id doesn't work", what do you mean? Do you get a traceback? Because that's the correct way of doing it.

Comment: @SoumyadipDM this is the correct method. I was referring to the dot notation pointing to `Ass..Re_.id == owner_id` Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @polpak Traceback Added and changes below original code.

Comment: But you didn't do what I said... `filter(Assessment_Results.owner_id == owner.id)`

Comment: @polpak Aww! I didn't see the `_` versus `.` I'll modify above and add the Error

Comment: owner is an instance of the owner model, but it is called user (you can see that in `owner = relationship('User', backref='assessment_results')` . New error occurs as a result of `owner_id == owner.id` (shown above)

Comment: That is true for the model, but it is not true within this method. The owner in the method (which is passed as a parameter) is actually a string (hence the traceback you have now). That means that create_category_rating is passing a string where it should be passing an owner object.

Comment: @polpak hmmm.. this is an issue. I need to pass a string. I have an inheritance class that takes this method and passes the string into an object. I'll add that above.. maybe it might clarify. Or maybe I need to approach it differently.

Comment: @polpak I updated the inheritance so you can see the cat taking in the string and passing an object. Thank you again for helping me understand this issue. I've been struggling with this for a long time now.

Comment: You are getting a string passed as owner, and assessment. If you want those to be model objects you will need to use the string to query the objects. This might need to be done in the test layer. It's really difficult to tell from what you've posted here..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88506/discussion-between-amarie-and-polpak).